# How to update SQL row based on two or more duplicate coluns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL table. I want to be able to insert a new row (if it doesn't exist) or update a value in an existing row (in this case `transaction` based TWO columns which are `(ds, item)`.

```
ID  ds          item           transactions
1   2020-02-25  Baba Ghanous   1.0
2   2020-02-25  Shawerma       1.0
3   2020-02-25  Steak          1.0
4   2020-02-25  fish n chips   1.0
5   2020-02-25  Besara         1.0
```

Initially, i started with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO forecast_sales (ds, item, transactions) VALUES('2020-02-25', 'Shawerma', 1.0) ON DUPLICATE (ds, item) UPDATE transaction=2.0
```

However, I get a Syntax error because Duplicate is used with the associated key of the table according to the documentation. My question is, is there a query that can allow me to produce the desired result?

Comment: Use single quotes for both string and date constants.

Answer (score 0):

Dates need to be quoted. The error message shows exactly where the syntax error starts.

[Documentation for INSERT ON DUPLICATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) shows `DUPLICATE (ds, item)` isn't part of the syntax allowed.