# SQL Can't upate table due to `Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "IF": syntax error)`

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a begginer in SQL. I'm trying to update a row in a SQL table if the table is not empty. I'm using the following query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM customers) THEN
    update customers set CustomerName= "David" where ConcactName="Jason";
Else
    -- insert clause;
```

However, I get the following error: `Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "IF": syntax error)`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can only use it statements in stored programs(procedures,functions,triggers,events)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it.  Just run the `update`:

```
update customers
    set CustomerName = 'David'
    where ContactName = 'Jason';
```

If no rows match the `where` condition, no rows are updated.

For the record, you can only use `if` in MySQL within a programming block -- which means in a trigger, user-defined function, or stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Initially, I was testing the if clause as part of a bigger query. The query is to update an existing row if it exists, or insert a new row into the table if it doesn't. Not sure if this changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE customers 
SET CustomerName = 'David' 
WHERE ConcactName = 'Jason'
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM `Table` );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Initially, I was testing the if clause as part of a bigger query. The query is to update an existing row if it exists, or insert a new row into the table if it doesn't. Not sure if this changes anything.

Comment: @IslamElkadi I can work with the data which you provide only. *The query is to update an existing row if it exists, or insert a new row into the table if it doesn't.* Use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `REPLACE`.

Comment: Am I able to update on something other than the Key? In the table, I have my key as an autogenerated INT. But I'd like to update on two more columns meeting a certain criteria. How would I go about doing so with a clause similar to the one above?

Comment: @IslamElkadi I think you'd create another question - without restrictions and simplifyings.

Comment: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200157/how-to-update-sql-row-based-on-two-or-more-duplicate-coluns